# Can I change Windows desktop environment?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-environments

I do not like Windows 7 default desktop environment and I would like to replace it. I do not know if it can be changed and what desktop environments are available for Windows.

I like Windows XP desktop environment, but Windows XP is becoming obsolete for newer applications, hardwares, drivers and games.

I would not use Windows, but I need to, because some applications and games are available only for Windows.

Comment: You should be able to change your Windows Theme to Windows Classic, which is the closest to the Windows XP Experience. But what did you not like from the Win7 desktop? It's basically the same as before, with added feature and new look and feel.

Comment: What @Gabriel Mongeon said...if you can be more specific about what you dislike, better recommendations can be made.  Do you just dislike the visuals, in which case a theme will suffice, or are there UI elements you dislike, in which case you might need to go as far as a whole shell replacement?

Comment: Hey IDK about you but I like everything about 7 over XP except 7's failure to be able to kill Zombied tasks :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst the other answers are completely valid, there ARE so-called shell replacements. A quick google search for "Windows 7 shell replacement" should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

http://techie-buzz.com/featured/download-windows-xp-theme-for-windows-7.html

If you are using Windows 7 and are nostalgic like me about Windows XP, you can now download a Windows XP theme and use it on Windows 7.

XP Luna is a theme for Windows 7 that will bring the look and feel of Windows XP to Windows 7, definitely worth it if you want the simple looks of XP and the power of Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel -> Personalization. From there you can change basic theme.

If you want to use Windows Classic (=Windows XP theme), you can change it from same place.

There is also 3rd party programs for modifying Windows behavior and look, but that is rather hard way to modify it.